# back-tick in ruby does not work with tail -f command

Tags: ruby, logging, tail

The code below does not print the output of `tail -f`. Why? How can I make it work?

```
#myApp.rb
`ls`               #works fine
`tail -f filename`      #does not work. why?
```

Comment: Is `"filename"` the literal name of the file (or a dummy name used just for your question)? Or is it the name of a variable that holds a string?

Comment: `filename` is a dummy for question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the follow option `-f` on `tail` the executed command will not immediately terminate.

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
  output appended data as the file grows;
```

The idea of using backticks (or the `%x` shortcut), as opposed to using `system('...')` is that these statements return the output of the executed commands. This way you could store the result in a variable:

```
dir_content = `ls`
```

`tail -f` spawns another process, this process keeps on writing to standard output without terminating. Hence, your statement is never finished. Without finishing the statement, a value cannot be returned. If you want to watch and output of a growing file, see the solution to the question:

[Watch/read a growing log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293695/watch-read-a-growing-log-file-with-ruby).

Alternatively, you could run the command through `system` like so:

```
system('tail -f filename')
```

What is the difference here? Instead of returning the outpout of the command, it will return true (command run successfully), false (unsuccessful) or nil (command execution failed). Due to the fact, that the output of the command is not redirected to the return statement running `tail -f` it will print the content to standard output.

If you are fine with getting the results to standard output you can simply put it into a Thread block. This way the growing content of `filename` is written to standard output and you can continue to execute other Ruby code.

```
Thread.new { system('tail -f filename') }
```

If you want to have complete control, capture the output in order to store it for retrieval at another point of your script then have a look at the answer to the following question which describes such an approach:

[Continuously read from STDOUT of external process in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154846/continuously-read-from-stdout-of-external-process-in-ruby)

It is based on the [PTY](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) module which creates and manages pseudo terminals. Basically you can spawn another terminal through this module. The code could then look like so:

```
require 'pty'
cmd = "tail -f filename" 
begin
  PTY.spawn(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, pid|
    begin
      # Do something with the output here: just printing to demonstrate it
      stdin.each { |line| print line }
    rescue Errno::EIO
      puts "Errno:EIO error, but this probably just means " +
            "that the process has finished giving output"
    end
  end
rescue PTY::ChildExited
  puts "The child process exited!"
end
```

Finally, there is also a socket approach. Open a socket in Bash or by using `socat`, pipe the output of `tail -f` to the socket and read in Ruby from the socket.

Comment: Your post is a muddled mess and describes what happens instead of explaining why it happens.  The op already knows what happens.  Downvoted.  The people that upvoted your post should explain why they upvoted it.  Your reasoning goes something like this: if you execute a command that doesn't return a value, it cannot write to stdout; but if you use ruby's system() method to execute a command which doesn't return a value, it will write to stdout.  Huh?

Comment: I haven't stated in any kind, that if you execute a command that does not return a value it cannot write to stdout. Also I don't see from the question what the OP already knows and what he does not know. Thanks for the comment though, I will try to improve the formulations.

Comment: platzhirsch wrote: _Without the termination no return value will be given and so nothing is printed._  What does that mean then?  Or to put it another way, is a command's return value or lack thereof relevant to whether a command can write to stdout?

Comment: @7stud Okay, thanks. I have edited the answer. Hopefully it clears things up.

Comment: @7stud That doesn't make any sense to my mind. The standard output reading is never finished, hence no return value can be given through running the command. If, by using backticks, an `IO` object or something alike would be returned and if `puts` would accept and `IO` object and continously read from this, then this would make sense. This, however, is simply not the case.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and if you include my comment in your answer, then your answer would explain WHY it happens.

Answer (score 1):

1) According to the backticks docs,

```
`cmd`
Returns the standard output of running cmd in a subshell.
```

So if you write:

```
puts `some command`
```

then ruby should print whatever some command outputs.

2) According to the tail man pages:

```
The tail utility displays the contents of file...to the standard
output.
```

But the command:

```
puts `tail -f some_file`
```

doesn't print anything despite the fact that running:

```
$ tail -f some_file
```

sends output to standard out.  The tail man pages also say

```
The -f option causes tail to not stop when
end of file is reached, but rather to wait
for additional data to be appended to the
[the file].
```

What does that mean?  And how is it relevant to the problem at hand?

Because running the program:

```
puts `tail -f some_file`
```

...hangs and doesn't output anything, you can infer that the backticks method must be trying to capture the *entire output* of the command.  In other words, **the backticks method does not read line by line from the command's standard output, i.e. *line oriented input*.  Instead, the backticks method reads file oriented input, i.e. a file at a time.** And because the command `tail -f some_file` never finishes writing to standard output, the backticks method never reads end of file, and it hangs while it waits for eof.

3) However, reading a command's output *a file at a time* is not the only way to read a command's output.  You can also read a command's output a line at a time using popen():

my_prog.rb:

```
IO.popen('tail -f data.txt') do |pipe| 
  while line = pipe.gets do  #gets() reads up to the next newline, then returns
    puts line
  end
end


--output(terminal window 1):--
$ ruby my_prog.rb 
A
B
C
<hangs>

--output(terminal window 2):--
echo 'D' >> data.txt

--output(terminal window 1):--
A
B
C
D
<hangs>
```

echo man pages:

```
The echo utility writes any specified operands...followed
by a newline (`\n') character.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because the backticks make a separate `System` call to run the commands within the backticks.
If you do `ps aux | grep tail`, you will be able to see that the tail process is in fact running.

The code is not showing any output because its waiting for tail to terminate and proceed to next statements - its not hung because it is displaying the output of tail command.

Even in normal operation, you have to do a `ctrl+C` to close the output of `tail -f`command. The `-f` is used to output appended data as the file grows, and hence `tail -f` keeps running.
Try to do a `kill -9 <pid_of_tail>` using the pid from `ps aux | grep tail`. Then the remaining part of your ruby code will start outputting the result.

The `ls`, `tail without -f` calls work because they terminate on their own.

If you are interested in doing a tail from ruby, you can have a look at this `file-tail` gem http://flori.github.io/file-tail/doc/index.html