# How to continuously watch a growing log file and parse changes in ruby

Tags: ruby, logging

Question says all about my requirement, but I'll try to explain in detail.

I have a log file, say `development.log`, and like a normal log file as requests are made, this file grows. I want to watch for this file and then if a new line(request) is added to this log file, I want to do something with this new line(say just print it). So everytime a new line is added, it should print in my rails console.

How can I achieve this in Ruby Script?

**EDIT:** Adding more info

Ex:

1. If I have a initial log file:

   ```
   # development.log
   GET abcd.com
   POST efgh.com
   ```
2. Now, I will run my ruby script, which will watch this log file for changes.
3. After 5 seconds the the log file becomes:

   ```
   # development.log
   GET abcd.com
   POST efgh.com
   GET newdomain.com
   POST newdomain.com
   ```
4. Now since the log file changed, My ruby console must print these new lines:

   ```
   # ruby output
   GET newdomain.com
   POST newdomain.com
   ```

Comment: I've checked a bit of `guard/listen` lib and a couple of others, but couldn't build a workaround around my requirement.

Comment: Is altering the code that writes to the log file an option? If not, is it important to perform the operation (e.g., printing to the console) each time a line is added to the file, or can the operation be performed periodically on groups of added lines? Some gems, such as [Logger](https://github.com/ruby/logger), may be of use.

Comment: Anything is fine - real time or periodically. I want to get the new lines added to the log file in my ruby script, so that I can perform an operation(e.g., printing that new line(s) to the console)

Comment: Hey @CarySwoveland I've updated my question for more info

Comment: Could you post with a method such as `def log(fname, str); puts str; open(fname, 'a') { |f| f.puts str }` (where `'a'` opens the file to *append* text)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the new line(s) in my `development.log` comes from the web server. I don't want a ruby script that appends the new lines in a file. What I want is, when a web server logs a request in `development.log`, my ruby script must be watching/listening to this log file and then perform some operation. It is similar like `tail -f development.log`, but with `tail` I cannot perform any operations.

Comment: I created various methods around various libs, nothing seems to work. So I'm looking for complete solution here

Comment: I think this [gem:File-Tail](https://github.com/flori/file-tail) should do the job for you. It allows you to invoke a block per line of added log.

Also, I think this question has been asked a lot before. Is your use case quite different from ones like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293695/watch-read-a-growing-log-file

Comment: @erosenin I came across that answer, but it only works againt `ERROR` pattern, I want to get all the requests(or lines). Do you have any workaround for that?

Comment: @erosenin , I got a workaround with `file-tail` gem, but it's not updated in 2.5 years. So not sure to use that in production. Is there a pure vanilla way?

Comment: @allenbrkn All you have to do is either edit the function to remove this check `puts "Found it!" if f.gets =~ pattern` and just do `puts f.gets`.

OR

pass the second argument to match everything `watch_for("log/development.log", /.*/)`